# How to check community user credentials via api

Tags: api, community

i am trying to use this flow: 
**Username-Password OAuth Authentication Flow**

grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNINVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82Hn
FVVX19KY1uA5mu0QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCscA9GE&client_secret=
1955279925675241571&username=testuser%40salesforce.com&password=mypassword123456

And it's work fine for salesforce users with salesforce licence.
If i added my ip in white list on profile-based level, then i can ignore token.

**Problem is:** when i try same with community user, i get error:

> grant type not supported

**Question is:** How can i send "user:password" to salesforce to determine what credentials is right?
My thought: maybe i should connect via REST with my Salesforce credentials and after that use something like login(username, password) function (from login controller class)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found this usefull for my case:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Login_Sample_(Partner)

```
    $authEndPoint = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/24.0/";   
        $USERNAME = $user_data['email'];
        $PASSWORD = $user_data['password'];
        $LOGINSCOPEHEADER = '00DcXXXXXXXX';  // your Salesforce.com Organization ID (Company information page)

        try {
          $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
          $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner.wsdl.xml');
          $header = new LoginScopeHeader($LOGINSCOPEHEADER);
          $mySforceConnection->setLoginScopeHeader($header);
          $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
          $user_info = $mySforceConnection->getUserInfo();
          //print_r($user_info);
          $array = (array)$user_info;

          header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK'); 

          echo "logged"; 

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request'); 
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
          echo $e->faultstring;
        }
```