# Username-Password OAuth Authentication for community users?

Tags: community, rest, soap, oauth, login

I have a native ios app and i want to login using the username password flow, From the POC i made i discovered that for community user, i dont get a security token which i was using while REST call to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

So I want to know is it possible to use username-password flow with community user.

I have already gone through other answers related to same questions in the community, none of them worked for me.

I have checked following links,

[Username-Password OAuth Authentication is working with the community users?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107762/username-password-oauth-authentication-is-working-with-the-community-users?rq=1)

[How to check community user credentials via api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71020/how-to-check-community-user-credentials-via-api)

[Customer Community login using REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111687/customer-community-login-using-rest-api)

also there are few links that suggest using soap API for authentication I tried a curl request but it didn't worked

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_quickstart_login.htm

```
curl https://uat-uat-rnc.cs8.force.com/callcenter/services/Soap/u/41.0 -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8" -H "SOAPAction: login" -d @login.txt
```

heres the content of login.txt

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:LoginScopeHeader>
      <ns1:organizationId>00Dl00Gt0000CrM</ns1:organizationId>
<ns1:portalId>0DB0l000888ZVGA2</ns1:portalId>
 </ns1:LoginScopeHeader>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:login>
      <ns1:username>harry@rnc.com.ccu</ns1:username>
      <ns1:password>India</ns1:password>
    </ns1:login>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the profile of the user make it as API enabled.

[image]

I was able to log in using api inside the community using the below soap login call.,

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <login xmlns="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com">
        <username>tomxxx@dsssd.com</username>
        <password>Nexxwussa123</password>
    </login>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

Also make sure you include header as

```
SOAPAction : Soap
```

endpoint: https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/T/41.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <loginResponse>
        <result>
            <metadataServerUrl>https://foooodle--UAT.csx7.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/41.0/00D8E00x009MIn</metadataServerUrl>
            <passwordExpired>false</passwordExpired>
            <sandbox>true</sandbox>
            <serverUrl>https://foooodle--UAT.csx7.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/T/41.0/00D8E0000009MIn</serverUrl>
            <sessionId>00D8xx0009MIn!AQUAQAKlWxxuowH_1DK7ic52WzqCrxgyDRaPsrr9L8JgGRpv7l5oBmVFJGSs2tsKuxWAPum7vT2IlM7AuGt7vf.qG.3M8R_</sessionId>
            <userId>0058E0000xxWmT4QAK</userId>
            <userInfo>
                <accessibilityMode>false</accessibilityMode>
                <chatterExternal>false</chatterExternal>
                <currencySymbol>£</currencySymbol>
                <orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit>5242880</orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit>
                <orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode>GBP</orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode>
                <orgDefaultCurrencyLocale>en_GB</orgDefaultCurrencyLocale>
                <orgDisallowHtmlAttachments>false</orgDisallowHtmlAttachments>
                <orgHasPersonAccounts>true</orgHasPersonAccounts>
                <organizationId>00D8x00009MInUAM</organizationId>
                <organizationMultiCurrency>false</organizationMultiCurrency>
                <organizationName>Pranya Finance</organizationName>
                <profileId>00e580000xydBAAQ</profileId>
                <roleId>00E8E0000xbcdhUAA</roleId>
                <sessionSecondsValid>28800</sessionSecondsValid>
                <userDefaultCurrencyIsoCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                <userEmail>pranayx@nce.com</userEmail>
                <userFullName>Tom Dealer tomm</userFullName>
                <userId>0058E000xWmT4QAK</userId>
                <userLanguage>en_US</userLanguage>
                <userLocale>en_GB</userLocale>
                <userName>tomxxx@dsssd.com</userName>
                <userTimeZone>Europe/London</userTimeZone>
                <userType>PowerPartner</userType>
                <userUiSkin>Theme3</userUiSkin>
            </userInfo>
        </result>
    </loginResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

You can also use this to call custom Apex Rest/Soap Webservices. It saves costs than using a full platform user license as Integration user.

Comment: This looked mighty promising, unfortunately for use we keep getting `Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out` for non-sandbox community user

Comment: @zaitsman what do you mean? I have used this in production.

Comment: The envelope you posted did not work for me, I had to add `<urn:organizationId>ORGIDHERE</urn:organizationId>` to get the session id.

Answer (score 0):

A better one that works...

Make authrequest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <urn:LoginScopeHeader>
      <urn:organizationId>00D3000034343yn</urn:organizationId>
    </urn:LoginScopeHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <urn:login>
        <urn:username>williambell9708@email.com</urn:username>
        <urn:password>ddsds5354342</urn:password>
    </urn:login>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And call it with:

```
curl -X POST -d @authrequest.xml https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/36.0 --header "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8;" -H "SOAPAction: login"
```

Then look into the result for token...

Comment: Use of login.salesforce.com suggests this is for a Salesforce or Salesforce Platform user rather than a Community User. Are you sure you are answering the question?

Comment: Worth also noting Saleforce explicitly recommends against this approach as it is a security risk.